# lspci output of NVMe SSD in M.2 slot

Tags: linux, ssd, motherboard, pci-express, nvme

I am developing some system management scripts and was wondering if a M.2 NVMe slot on the motherboard shows up in lspci output? Unfortunately, I don't have the hardware currently to test this (I have a NVMe SSD in an HBA sitting in a PCIe slot, but not an M.2 slot built on to the motherboard).

If anyone reading this has the needed hardware (ie., populated M.2 slot on motherboard having an NVMe SSD), could they help a fellow developer by providing the lspci output showing the NVMe drive in the M.2 slot?

Comment: Googling finds [this example lscsi output](https://itpeernetwork.intel.com/finding-your-new-intel-ssd-for-pcie-think-nvme-not-scsi/).

Answer (score 0):

So if you just want to know is a drive is detected ... below you can see my samsung NVME M.2 drive:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Q370 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V (rev 10)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller PM9A1/PM9A3/980PRO
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
$
```

I was not expecting that lspci would also identify the drive, I assumed it would just tell you here is one, but low and behold it reports it's a Samsung 980PRO.